# Solving for the derivative at the point $z = 0$ for the function $f(z) = z^2 - \bar{z}^2$

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, complex-numbers

I'm trying to solve for the derivative of $f(z) = z^2 - \bar{z}^2$ using the limit definition (I'm positive that it can be done with power rule, but given my track record recently, I'm not going to claim so).

Since the derivative only exists at $0$, using the limit definition I got $\frac{z^2 - \bar{z}^2}{z}$ which then became $\frac{z^2}{z} - \frac{ \bar{z}^2 }{z}$ and thus $z - \frac{ \bar{z}^2 }{z}$.

Here's where I'm stuck - I want to cancel the $z$ in my denominator. I tried multiplying by the conjugate, but all I got was $\frac{ \bar{z}^3 }{|z|}$ which doesn't help at all. I also observed initially that the original equation can be written as $f(z) = (4i)(Re(z))(Im(z))$, but going down that route didn't help much at all either. I'm thinking this is one of those questions where maybe I should use an inequality or something similar, but I'm not so sure. Any help here would be appreciated! I'm trying my best to understand.

Comment: The absolute value of the ratio tends to $0$ when $z\to 0.$

Comment: Oh! Because of the difference in powers?

Comment: Just multiply the top and bottom of $\frac{\bar z ^2}{z}$ by $z^2$ to get $\frac {|z|^4}{z^3}$. Take absolute value to get $|z|$. Since the limit of the absolute value goes to zero, the original limit must go to zero.

Comment: $$\left|{z^2-\overline{z}^2\over z}\right |\le {|z|^2+|z|^2\over |z|}=2|z|$$

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Thanks! In general, I know absolute value can be a wonky function so I've been a little hesitant to play around with it. Should I be on the lookout for absolute value tricks like that throughout the whole class?

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Admittedly, I'm not certain I understand your reasoning - is this similar to Squeeze Theorem in the sense that because the function we have is smaller than the function we can create, the limit tends in the same direction?

Comment: Yes, Ryszard is applying the squeeze theorem. It's definitely the best way to solve the problem. The lower bound is $0$.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Ok, I see it now! When it comes to Squeeze theorem, how can I "see" the function I should choose? Because here it didn't occur to me at all and I'd like to get better at solving these problems.

Comment: You don't see the end result to start, you instead simplify what you're given bit-by-bit (via asymptotic approximations, removing signs, using series up to appropriate order, etc etc) until you get to something tractable. Notice the triangle inequality was also used for the absolute value. Triangle inequality for norms is sorta one of those fundamental tools for inequalities you'll use again and again throughout your math studies.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Yeah, I see it! That makes sense. Thank you so much for your help, this class is hard and I'm trying my best to walk away with a deep understanding.